# Storing in Plist?

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

I was just wondering how one could store this data in a plist, with the same output.Right now I am using NSObject. Do I store these in separate dictionary's? but then how can i call them back to fill the tableData array.

```
Exercises *exercise1 = [Exercises new];
exercise1.name = @"Barbell Rollouts";
exercise1.materials = @"30 min";
exercise1.imageFile = @"BarbellRollouts.jpg";
exercise1.sets = @"2";
exercise1.reps = @"10";
exercise1.instructions = @"Hello";
exercise1.status = @"Dynamic";

Exercises *exercise2 = [Exercises new];
exercise2.name = @"Barbell Trunk Rotation";
exercise2.materials = @"30 min";
exercise2.imageFile = @"BarbellTrunkRotation.jpg";
exercise2.sets = @"2";
exercise2.reps = @"10";
exercise2.instructions = @"";
  exercise2.status = @"Dynamic";

Exercises *exercise3 = [Exercises new];
exercise3.name = @"Bent Knee Leg Raises";
exercise3.materials = @"30 min";
exercise3.imageFile = @"BentKneeLegRaises.jpg";
exercise3.sets = @"2";
exercise3.reps = @"10";
exercise3.instructions = @"";
  exercise3.status = @"Dynamic";

Exercises *exercise4 = [Exercises new];
exercise4.name = @"Bicycle Manouver";
exercise4.materials = @"30 min";
exercise4.imageFile = @"BicycleManouver.jpg";
exercise4.sets = @"2";
exercise4.reps = @"10";
exercise4.instructions = @"";
  exercise4.status = @"Dynamic";

Exercises *exercise5 = [Exercises new];
exercise5.name = @"Boat Pose";
exercise5.materials = @"30 min";
exercise5.imageFile = @"BoatPose.jpg";
exercise5.sets = @"2";
exercise5.reps = @"10";
exercise5.instructions = @"";
  exercise5.status = @"Static";

Exercises *exercise6 = [Exercises new];
exercise6.name = @"Bosu Boat Pose";
exercise6.materials = @"30 min";
exercise6.imageFile = @"BosuBoatPose.jpg";
exercise6.sets = @"2";
exercise6.reps = @"10";
exercise6.instructions = @"";
  exercise6.status = @"Static";


tableData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:exercise1,exercise2,exercise3,exercise4,exercise5,exercise6,nil];
```

Comment: Implement the `<NSCoding>` protocol or set `NSDictionary` key-value pairs manually. Do the inverse when loading back from file. It ain't hard at all, if you dig a bit in the docs, you should be able to figure it out yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement the `NSCoding` [protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

In your header:

```
@interface Exercise : NSObject <NSCoding>
// Your public property list
@end
```

In your implementation file:

```
@interface Exercise()
// Your private property list
@end

@implementation Exercise

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }

    self.name = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"name"];
    self.sets = [decoder decodeIntegerForKey:@"sets"];
    // similar approach for other properties

    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    [encoder encodeObject:self.name forKey:@"name"];
    [encoder encodeInteger:self.sets forKey:@"sets"];
    // similar approach for other properties
}
@end
```

You should now be able to use `NSKeyedArchiver` to save into your plist and `NSKeyedUnarchiver` to read it back:

```
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:exercise toFile:@"/path/to/file"];
[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:@"/path/to/file"];
```